# Check if named tables exist VBA Excel 2007

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to determine if a table exists, using VBA Excel 2007, and if it exists then delete it.

I am looping through an array of table names.

My code is below:

```
' Allocate
Dim lIndex                                      As Long

' Allocate table header values in array
Dim sTableNames(1 To Constants.lNumTables)      As String

' Populate array
sTableNames(1) = Constants.sTableNameKpiAllIncidents
sTableNames(2) = Constants.sTableNameSlaAllManualHelpdeskIncidents
sTableNames(3) = Constants.sTableNameSlaAllManualIncidents
sTableNames(4) = Constants.sTableNameKpiAllAutomaticIncidents

' Work in worksheet Statistics
With Worksheets(Constants.sSheetNameStatistics)

    ' Loop through all tables
    For lIndex = 1 To UBound(sTableNames)

        ' Check if table already exists
        If Not .ListObjects(sTableNames(lIndex)) Is Nothing Then

            ' Delete table
            .ListObjects(sTableNames(lIndex)).Delete

        End If

    Next

End With
```

My code works as long as these tables exist in my worksheet. I have also tried replacing the line

```
If Not .ListObjects(sTableNames(lIndex)) Is Nothing Then
```

with the line

```
 If .ListObjects(sTableNames(lIndex)).Count > 0 Then
```

but it still doesn't work.

Does anybody know a way to get this to work?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What error do you get? The 'dirty' quick fix would be to add `On Error Resume Next` before the `....Delete` line.

Comment: I get run-time error '9': Subscript out of range

Comment: It makes Excel not interrupt code execution in case it encounters an error. This is 'dirty' because all errors appear for a reason (in your case: the macro is trying to delete something that doesn't exist) and by jumping over it you may overlook other bugs.

Comment: Thank you! I've inserted the line before 

If Not .ListObjects(sTableNames(lIndex)) Is Nothing Then

and it worked!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Error handling as nhee suggests is the *right* approach.

As a UDF the suggestion above would be quicker with:

```
Function TableExists(ws As Worksheet, tblNam As String) As Boolean
Dim oTbl As ListObject
On Error Resume Next
Set oTbl = ws.ListObjects(tblNam)
TableExists = Not oTbl Is Nothing
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

The following UDF will return a boolean if a table exists

```
  Function TableExists(ws As Worksheet, tblNam As String) As Boolean
    Dim oTbl As ListObject
      For Each oTbl In ws.ListObjects
        If oTbl.Name = tblNam Then
            TableExists = True
            Exit Function
        End If
      Next oTbl
      TableExists = False
    End Function
```